# Vim open file with h and l

Tags: vim

So I have the following lines in my vimrc to scroll through autocompletion using jk.

```
" Making autocompletion work with jk
inoremap <expr> j ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n>"):("j"))
inoremap <expr> k ((pumvisible())?("\<C-p>"):("k"))
```

I was wondering if there would be a way to scroll through `:tabe<Tab>` suggestions using `h`and `l`? That's what would seem the most natural to me, however I haven't been able to find anything on how to do that.

Comment: just replace j,k with h,l? or I misunderstood your question

Comment: `:tabe` suggestions mechanism doesn't work with `pumvisible()`, but with another function that I don't know of.

Comment: ach.. `:tabe`! you can press `<tab>` or left/right arrow to navigate. if you press h,l to navigate, what if you want to create a file "foo.h" or "l.bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using command line completion, whether you use `wildmenu` or not and whatever value you have set for `wildmode`, your cursor stays in the command line and whatever printable character you hit is inserted including, of course, `h` and `l`.

With that in mind, do you *really* think it would be wise to abandon the ability to insert `h` and `l` in the command line?

If you don't like `<Tab>` you could try the `wildchar` option but you won't be able to get rid of or replace `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` and the arrows.

Also, command line completion is a generic feature that is not limited to `:tabe`. `:tabe` is a red herring, here.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought about that... I also didn't know of `<C-n>`/`<C-p>`, and they're actually a good solution to my problem because the right hand doesn't get as far with them as with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

To remap `h` and `l` looks weird to me. They are really usefull, at least you need it to write, type commands etc...

If you want an easy autocompletion tips you should add these lines in your vimrc :

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode =list:longest,list:full
```

And then add the SuperTab function, it allows you to autocomplete with `Tab` and navigate into the menu with Tab also. Here is the code :

```
imap <Tab> <C-R>=SuperTab()<CR> 


function! SuperTab()
if (strpart(getline('.'),col('.')-2,1)=~'^\W\?$')
  return "\<Tab>"
else
  return "\<C-n>"
endif
endfunction
```

Hope it helps !